# encrypt a list of string with Hashicorp Vault Transit Engine

Tags: encryption, hashicorp-vault

I need to encrypt a list of strings with the [Hashicorp Vault Transit Engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/transit#encrypt-data).

I would like to avoid making one HTTP call for each string. If I use the **[batch_input](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/transit#batch_input)** list with body

```
{
    "batch_input": [{
        "context": "YQ==",
        "plaintext": "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
    },{
        "context": "Yg==",
        "plaintext": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="
    }]
}
```

the response is of the type:

```
[...]
"batch_results": [{
    "ciphertext": "vault:v1:0Yl3h8fxZYYAPy9svqUU1J7m64QPSq9qJW5scDE/fEWq7RGwOu33"
},{
    "ciphertext": "vault:v1:rhSoZIQe/kFmw/FahDdPO5a/Xq8zTNniKTMI6oSiFL4bRDETr6rG"
}]
[...]
```

However, from this response, I am not able to understand to which plaintext each ciphertext refers.

**There is a way to identify them?**

Comment: Request and response are congruent, i.e. the Nth ciphertext corresponds to the Nth plaintext. I was sure this was documented in the API reference, but I can't seem to find it now, hence only a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: If you don't want to take my word for it and you're somewhat familiar with Go, you can look at [the code](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/v1.7.2/builtin/logical/transit/path_encrypt.go#L345-L374).